# Trouble with converting date format in python using datetime.strptime

Tags: python

Hi everyone I have a code like this to calculate the exact day on six_months back but unfortunately it prints the yy-mm-dd format and I want the dd/mm/yy format how do I do it(I tried to convert but it doesn't work)?What's wrong with my code?

```
  import datetime
  six_months = str(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(6*365/12-1)
  datetime.datetime.strptime(six_months, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')
```

expected output=04/02/2017
current output=2017-02-04

Comment: I get the expected output with your commands (copy/paste).

Comment: NB a parenthese is missing at the end of second line

Comment: I get the correct output as well. Did you assign the result of the last line to a new variable?

Comment: Why do you make the result of the subtraction a string, then parse it back into a datetime object?

Comment: I execute you're code and it's output is fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, you just forgot to save to result of

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(six_months, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')
```

to any variable. `strptime` doesn't change the object it is called on in any way, it returns a string.

Comment: oh well that's weird

Comment: how do I do it?

Comment: import datetime
six_months = str(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(6*365/12-1)
a=datetime.datetime.strptime(six_months, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d/%m/%y')

Comment: It's an invalid syntax for some reason

Comment: Invalid syntax where?

Comment: invalid syntax at a

Comment: "a" has invalid syntax

Comment: for some reason ,I am using python 3.6

Comment: The syntax error is a missing `)` before `a`. As @zezollo remarked.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon your algorithm for computing *6 months back* doesn't correspond to the real-world understanding of that phrase. Six months back from 4 August is 4 February and your computation gives the right answer for that. But six months back from 4 September is 4 March, and your computation gives the answer 7 March.

Your code also unnecessarily formats the computed date to a string, and then has to parse the string back into a date to get the dd/mm/yy format you want.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import *
six_months = datetime.date.today() + relativedelta(months=-6)
print (f"{six_months:%d/%m/%y}")
```

Output (until tomorrow) is

```
04/02/17
```